# Listen to Libby audiobooks at 3x/4x speed?

Tags: audiobook

Audible.com audiobooks have 4x speed, but Libby seems to only have 2x speed. Is there any way to "hack" or, say, "transfer" the libby audiobook to another player so you can get 4x speed?

Comment: Convert to say mp3, then playback however you like? (I'm not sure how to do that though, just a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Use Overdrive app, download the audio book a proper File Manager app, go to

`Android/data/com.overdrive.mobile.android.mediaconsole/files/OverDrive/` and play it with another audiobook player that does support faster speed (for example Smart audiobook Player for android)